# algorithm for random extraction of elements

Tags: random, sample

I have some issues understanding why the following procedure for performing random sampling from a set of objects work correctly:

suppose I have a population of 100 males and I want to extract 30 of them. One procedure proposed is the following:

assign to the first element of the list a probability of 30/100 and generate a random number n between 0 and 1. If n<30/100, the element gets selected, otherwise it does not.

If it gets selected, then move to the second element and assign it a probability of 29/99,otherwise move to the secodn record without selecting the first one and assign to it a probability of 30/99.

Eventually, proceding in this way we should reach the desired result of 30 random elements extracted from 100, but I do not understand conceptually why this leads to the correct solution.

Comment: This is a nice question involving conditional probability, but since it doesn’t involve any programming it’s off-topic here. I’ve voted to close and migrate it to stats.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 1):

**I will give a hand wave explanation and leave mathematics for brevity**

There are two probabilities involved:

1. The probability of an element getting selected
2. The oracle that selects an element

Since each element has an equal probability of being selected, after each selection we make sure that the probability is adjusted according to the number of total samples left and the number of samples left to be chosen.

Initially, the probability of each element being selected is 30/100. The oracle will toss a multi-headed coin. There are two situations now:

1. We select the first element if the probability of the coin < 30/100. Now we have 99 elements left and we need to choose 29 from them. Since each element has an equal probability of selection, we adjust the probability of each element to 29/100 and proceed with the oracle again.
2. If the oracle does not select the current element, we are left with 99 elements and we need to choose 30 from them. Since each element has an equal probability of selection, we adjust the probability of each element to 30/99 and proceed with the oracle again.

Comment: Thanks a lot: why should we consider the probability of the first element to be extracted 30/100? I do not understand why the probability assignment changes according to the number of elements that are left to be extracted